# Why are vows to fast undertaken at mincha a stated exception in Hatarat Nedarim?

Tags: prayer-book

In the last part of Hatarat Nedarim, when talking about future vows, vows to fast undertaken at mincha are a specific exception. Why this exception and no other?

Answer (score 5):

The Chazon Ish (cited in [Kol Nidrei](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=55475#p=77), by R' Yitzchak Shtesman) says that it's because otherwise this declaration would cancel the vow to fast (unless he specifically remembers the condition at the time and is knowingly overriding it). The result would be that his fasts wouldn't be preceded by a proper kabbalah, which is needed for it to be a proper fast (Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 562:5).